# Не могу сформировать запрос SELECT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Описание базы данных]

---

Не могу выполнить задание.
"Вывести список отделов, сотрудники из которых работают в самом большом проекте (по количеству участников)"

```
SELECT Department FROM DEP
INNER JOIN EMP ON DEP.ID_Dep=EMP.ID_Dep
INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP ON EMP.ID_Emp=PROJECT_EMP.ID_Emp
GROUP BY Department
```

этот запрос выводит список отделов, задействованных в проектах. Как дальше делать - знаний не хватает.

```
SELECT Department
FROM DEP
INNER JOIN EMP ON DEP.ID_Dep=EMP.ID_Dep
INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP ON EMP.ID_Emp=PROJECT_EMP.ID_Emp
GROUP BY Department
HAVING COUNT(Name)=
(SELECT max(qwe) FROM (SELECT COUNT(Name) as qwe
FROM DEP
INNER JOIN EMP ON DEP.ID_Dep=EMP.ID_Dep
INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP ON EMP.ID_Emp=PROJECT_EMP.ID_Emp
GROUP BY Department) tmp)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в Ваш вопрос код, который Вы написали и попробовали выполнить. Опишите, что получилось, и как это отличается от ожидаемого.

Comment: SELECT Department
FROM DEP
INNER JOIN EMP ON DEP.ID_Dep=EMP.ID_Dep
INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP ON EMP.ID_Emp=PROJECT_EMP.ID_Emp
GROUP BY Department

Comment: этот запрос выводит список отделов, задействованных в проектах. как дальше делать - знаний не хвататет

Comment: может использовать функцию MAX()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, под рукой нету сервера, чтобы проверить, но примерно так:

```
select * from DEP d
inner join EMP e on d.ID_Dep = e.ID_Dep
inner join PROJECT_EMP pe on pe.ID_Emp = e.ID_Emp
where pe.ID_Project = 
    (select top 1 ID_Project from PROJECT_EMP
     group by ID_Project
     order by count(ID_Emp) desc)
```

Опционально можно добавить джойн к таблице `PROJECT` и условие `Pr_end is not null`, если в задании подразумеваются *текущие (незавершенные)* проекты.

Comment: Немного не то. Должен выводиться Технический отдел.

Comment: @neko69 что такое технический отдел?

Comment: Department из таблицы DEP
Как вы вставляете код, чтобы его можно было нормально прочитать? Хочу показать свой кривой код

Comment: @neko69 Department из таблицы DEP -- это колонка с наименованиями отделов. А что такое "технические отдел"?

Comment: @neko69 в вопросе и ответе надо выделить код и нажать на кнопку {}. В комментариях код не форматируется и поэтому его в комментариях не пишут. Добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите. Прощу прощения за чушь, которую я несу - очень слабый уровень знаний у меня.

Answer (score 0):

А если вот так:

```
SELECT
  Department
FROM
  DEP d
  INNER JOIN EMP e ON d.ID_Dep = e.ID_Dep
  INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP pe ON pe.ID_Emp = e.ID_Emp
WHERE
  pe.ID_Project = ( 
    SELECT
      ID_Project
    FROM
      PROJECT_EMP
    GROUP BY
      ID_Project
    ORDER BY
      count(ID_Emp) DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  ) 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Department 
FROM dep 
INNER JOIN emp ON (emp.id_dep=dep.id_dep) 
INNER JOIN project_emp AS pe ON (pe.id_emp=emp.id_emp)
WHERE id_project = (
  SELECT id_pe, COUNT(*) AS c FROM project_emp 
  GROUP BY id_pe order by c 
  DESC limit 1);
```